# Creating and extracting data from trap representations via memcpy

Tags: c, language-lawyer, memcpy

If we use `memcpy` to copy arbitrary data into a variable, potentially creating a trap representation, can we reliably extract that data later so long as the value of that variable is never accessed? In other words, does the following program avoid undefined behavior and reliably pass the `assert` test at the end?

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    // Create some random data
    unsigned char original_data[ 100 ];
    for( int i = 0; i < sizeof( original_data ); ++i )
        original_data[ i ] = rand();
    
    // A float array whose size is at least as big as the data
    float float_array[ sizeof( original_data ) / sizeof( float ) + 1 ] = { 0 };
    
    // Create probable trap representations in the float array
    memcpy( float_array, original_data, sizeof( original_data ) );
    
    // Do other things without ever accessing the float values in the array
    // ...
    
    // Extract data
    unsigned char extracted_data[ sizeof( original_data ) ];
    memcpy( extracted_data, float_array, sizeof( original_data ) );
    
    // original_data and extracted_data should now store the same data
    for( int i = 0; i < sizeof( original_data ); ++i )
        assert( extracted_data[ i ] == original_data[ i ] );
    
    return 0;
}
```

Obviously, the mere existence of a trap representation does not cause undefined behavior, since any uninitialized variable could contain one. But is it possible that the trap representations could somehow spontaneously change between the calls to `memcpy`?

Note that this is a language lawyer question about this specific scenario, so I’m *not* asking about how we can copy or store data *without* creating trap representations.

Comment: [§6.2.4 ¶2 of the ISO C11 standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.4p2) says: `"An object [...] retains its last-stored value throughout its lifetime."` It is worth noting that the term "value", not "representation", is used. According to [6.2.6.1 ¶5](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.6.1p5), an object with a trap representation does not have a value. So the question whether an object with a trap representation is guaranteed to maintain its representation throughout its lifetime is justified.

Comment: `memcpy` is specified to copy the bytes of an object (C 2018 7.24.2.1) and to copy them exactly (7.24.1 3: as if by `unsigned char`, so each setting of bits in a byte is a valid `unsigned char` value and is different from each other setting). So each byte copied from `original_data` to `float_array` and from `float_array` to `extracted_data` is copied exactly. The only way differences can arise is if changes occur spontaneously in objects. But 6.2.6.1 2 tells us that an object **is** its bytes…

Comment: … The fact that two different sets of byte values might represent the same value in the object’s type does not mean those bytes may be changed spontaneously (e.g., by some “smart” page-out page-in method that saves and restores values rather than bytes). All places in the standard where it says that different representations of a value (including changes in padding bits) may be used occur when some operation is being performed, such as assigning a value. So the bytes will never change spontaneously.

Comment: Also, 3.15 defines *object* as “region of data storage in the execution environment, the contents of which can represent values.” So, the fundamental thing C builds on is that an object is stored data. The semantics of values are built upon that, so rules about padding bits and multiple representations and stuff come later. The starting point is that an object is data stored in memory.